# Customizing date in tooltip when datgrouping enabled

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that has datagrouping enabled and a tooltip on the x and y axis. I also have a table that shows all the data displayed in the chart.

The problem is for large datasets, when the user hovers over the chart the last date shown in the x-axis tooltip does not match the last date shown in the table. Instead, I think it shows the first date in the set of data that was grouped.

I know datagrouping has an approximation option that lets the you set what value is displayed (i.e. open or close). However, this approximation setting seems to only apply to the value and not for the date. I want both to be set to "close". Is there a way to do this that I'm just missing?

To be clear for a dataset of that is being grouped: 
[(1/1, 1), (1/2, 2), (1/3, 3), (1/4, 4)] 
with approximation set as close

The x-axis tooltip is showing 1/1 and the y-axis is showing 4 but I want the x-axis tooltip to show 1/4.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in online code editor like jsfiddle? Try to simplify the example to only show this problem. It could be a bug.

Comment: So for some reason I can't reproduce the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/12jmughd/39/ - this is the basic state that I want to be in but changing the approximation doesn't seem to be changing anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts dataGrouping selects a group of points, approximates the value of the group and by default creates a point with a date of the first point and the calculated value of the whole set. You can shift it to the middle by setting `dataGrouping.smoothed = true`.

However, you can customize the tooltip so that it shows a range of date e.g `Friday, Aug 14 - Sunday, Aug 16, 2015`. Check demo and code posted below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/three-series-1000-points.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: 'average',
        smoothed: true,
        units: [
          ['day', [3]]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'ADBE',
    data: ADBE,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lba4g3kj/

**Api reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation 
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.smoothed

Comment: So there isn't a way to show just the last value and date of the group of points then? I would prefer to not display the whole range

Comment: You can only shift the group to the middle by using `dataGrouping.smoothed = true`.

Comment: What are the open or close options for approximation for then?

Comment: Approximation options ("average", "averages", "open", "high", "low", "close") are for value which represents grouped data. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation, https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.smoothed